# Symbol \pm is lower than the number next to it

Tags: symbols, unicode-math

Why does the `\pm` sign is ower compared to the number next to it? Is it normal behaviour? How can I raise it so to be at the same level as the number?

My distribution is Vanilla TeX and it is installed less than a week ago so it is updated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*Bold,
    ItalicFont=*It,
    BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
    Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

$$x= \pm 1$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please read [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)...

Comment: Note that `unicode-math` already loads `fontspec`, so no need to load both

Comment: @darthbith I know it, someone has mention it previously. I do it just in case. Thank you though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following, stripped-down version of your example reproduces the positioning problem you've encountered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$x= \pm 1$
\end{document}
```

The culprit appears to be the instruction `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, which loads the Latin Modern Math fonts. If the package isn't loaded, the positioning problem with the `\pm` symbol goes away, because fonts from the amsfonts collection are loaded instead. In a deeper sense, the culprit should be called the Latin Modern Math font. (See also @egreg's answer for a way to fix the bug introduced in a recent version of the Latin Modern Math fonts.)

Judging from your example code, the reason for loading the `unicode-math` package is so that you can run the instruction `\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}`. If you can make do without this alternate form of the `\varnothing` symbol, I suggest you simply not load the `unicode-math` package and drop the `\setmathfont` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
$x= \pm 1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is not minimal as I usually don't know which package depends on what output exactly, so I remove the ones I am absolutely sure that are not needed and leave the rest. Furthermore that way I have learned so many things about dependencies.

Comment: I get nothing with “LM Math”; check whether you have a very old version of Latin Modern Math (that used to be called like that).

Comment: @egreg: from the log file: `Package: unicode-math 2014/06/30 v0.7f Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX`, `lualatex-math 2014/08/18 v1.4`, and `luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "LM Math" -> "LMMATH-v0903.otf"`. Is that a really old version of the otf file?

Comment: `otfinfo -v latinmodern-math.otf` gives me `Version 1.959`

Comment: @egreg - Indeed, a by now four-year-old version of LM-MATH was still hanging around. I've deleted it, and now the second "solution" no longer works on my system either (MacTeX2015 pre-release). Will edit my answer to delete the second solution. Thanks for alerting me to this issue.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be a “design decision” (read “bug”) by the developers of Latin Modern Math.

Here is the evidence; I typeset the character in text mode, so it can't be influenced by possible effects of automatic math spacing or vertical shifting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\newfontface{\test}{latinmodern-math.otf}


\begin{document}

{\test\char"B1 +} $x= \pm 1$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Fixed version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\ORIpm\pm
  \let\pm\shifteduppm
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shifteduppm}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\shifted@up@pm\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\shifted@up@pm}{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\ORIpm$}%
}
\makeatother

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\newfontface{\test}{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

{\test\char"B1 +} $x= \pm 1$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the usage in math is as expected.

Alternative solution: use the `\pm` symbol from good old Computer Modern:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareSymbolFont{oldsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{oldsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\CMpm}{\mathbin}{oldsymbols}{"06}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\pm\CMpm}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\newfontface{\test}{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

{\test\char"B1 +} $x= \pm 1$

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the *fixed version* you use `\mathpalette` but then you don't use the first argument.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I see the same "design decision" in STIX TWO MATH under Lualatex, and this code repairs it there as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the font you choose. You should use an other font if you dislike this sign. So with this font it's normal. Do you need the line :

```
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
```

maybe you can reassign the base font only for the \pm sign, like you did for \int for example

p.s. : I didn't know Vanilla TeX. My answer is correct for XeLaTeX, but I think it should also work for Vanilla.

Comment: The OP is already using the instruction `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}`.